# PHP I want to create a html table using php

Tags: php

hi heres my attempted code, the first while statement works for the rows(works for the weights0, but i cant get it to work with the columns(heights). it works so if min_height input value is 20 and max_height is 50 the columns would look like this 20 25 30 35 40 45 50. my code currently works for the rows but not columns, can anyone help?

```
<?php
$rowiStep = 5;
$coliStep = 5;
// Get these
$iweightMin = $_GET["min_weight"];
$iweightMax = $_GET["max_weight"];
$iheightMin = $_GET["max_height"];
$iheightmax = $_GET["min_height"];

$iCur = $iweightMin;
$iCol = $iheightMin;
print('<table class="table">');
print('<tr ><td>Height/</br>Weight</td>');
while ($iCur <= $iweightMax) {
    printf('<tr><td>%d</td></tr>', $iCur);
    $iCur += $rowiStep;
}

$rowiCol = $iheightMin;

while ($iCol <= $iheightmax) {
   printf('<tr><td></td>', $iCol);
   $iCol += $rowiCol;
}

print ('</tr>');
print('</table>');  

?>
```

Comment: If you're saying you don't get output for the column set, you're missing a %d in the column's printf.

Comment: HTML tables are formed row by row, not column by column, so your approach makes no sense.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your desired output, and the input used to get it?

Comment: Looking at the the current code, I see a lot of misbalanced tags. Lot of opened tr's that are not closed. Maybe it will help if you post exactly what the intent of your implementation is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to print a height/weight matrix; try this:

```
$rowiStep = 5;
$coliStep = 5;
$output = array(
    '<table>'
);

for( $row_val = $_GET['min_weight'], $row_max <= $_GET['max_weight'];
     $row_val < $row_max;
     $row_val += $rowistep )
{
    $output[] = '<tr><td>' . $row_val . '</td>';
    for( $col_val = $_GET['min_height'], $col_val <= $_GET['max_height'];
         $col_val < $col_max;
         $col_val += $colistep )
    {
        $output[] = '<td>' . $col_val . '</td>';
    }
    $output[] = '</tr>';
}
$output[] = '</table>';
echo implode( "\n", $output );
```

This will produce output like this:

```
|min_weight            |min_height|min_height+colIStep|min_height+2colIstep|...|
|min_weight + rowIstep |min_height|min_height+colIStep|min_height+2colIstep|...|
|min_weight + 2rowIstep|min_height|min_height+colIStep|min_height+2colIstep|...|
|...|
```

What output are you looking for?

Comment: im basically trying to do the following with the column instead of rows                                                            <?php
$iStep = 5;

// Get these
$iweightMin = $_GET["min_weight"];
$iweightMax = $_GET["max_weight"];
$iheightMin = $_GET["max_height"];
$iheightmax = $_GET["min_height"];

$iCur = $iweightMin;
$iCol = $iheightMin;
print('<table class="table">');
print('<tr ><td>Height/</br>Weight</td>');
while ($iCur <= $iweightMax)
{
    printf('<tr><td>%d</td></tr>', $iCur);
    $iCur += $iStep;
}

   
?>

Comment: Would you mind editing your original question to include and example of the output you're looking for?